# Excel vba copy row and paste one row down based on a number in cell

Tags: excel, vba

Hi guys need little help on VBA macro
I have data on sheet, in row 36 from A36 to Q36 that i need to copy one row down based on a number from cell S36. So if number in S36 is 5 that means that i need to copy row 36 five times from that row. Number in cell S36 goes from 0  if 0 do not copy.

Comment: What have you done so far to achieve your goal? Do you have any code?

Comment: please clarify. maybe try to break it down to its essential part, something like "copy cell A if C == 9, else copy cell B"

Comment: This question is vague. Please provide more details. Possibly the code or an image of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'd suggest you record a macro that copies what you want the ONE time and then post the macro here and ask for specific advice on how to make it "dynamic" with some variables (ie, 'copyNum = S36'), how to build a LOOP will be handy using copyNum as the variable to iterate over. Also, how to get rid of using the Select Statements that come with all macro recordings.

Answer (score 0):

This is method based upon ranges. You might want to use `times_to_copy+1`, I could not tell from your question. I have not tested if this works correctly with formulas, etc. The code assumes the active sheet is the one where you want the code to apply.

```
Sub copy_cat()

Dim main_range As Range
Dim times_to_copy As Integer
Dim copy_to_range As Range

If (times_to_copy > 0) Then
    Set main_range = ActiveSheet.Range("A36:Q36")
    times_to_copy = ActiveSheet.Range("S36").Value
    Set copy_to_range = main_range.Resize(times_to_copy, main_range.Columns.Count)
    ' or Set copy_to_range = main_range.Resize(times_to_copy+1, main_range.Columns.Count) dunno
    copy_to_range = main_range.Value
End If

End Sub
```